# count values between two ranges in mysql

Tags: mysql, sum, range

I have a table something like this

| fromrank | torank | prize | poolid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 4500 | 72 |
| 2 | 4 | 1500 | 72 |
| 5 | 6 | 250 | 72 |

now i want to calculate the sum of prize using **mysql query**
for eg 1st rank get 4500 and 2nd rank to 4th rank each will get 1500 and 5th and 6th rank user get 250 each so the sum of prize should be 9500 on the basis of poolid but when i tried to sum only prize i get 6250 but the actual sum is 9500

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is to multiply prize to the ranks difference + 1

```
select sum(prize * (torank - fromrank + 1))
  from test_table;
```

[dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7n29qNqDk6Jnpdjhwp8VFy/0)

Comment: thanks this query really worked for me

Comment: @arun no problems. Mark this my answer as solution please